# how to stabilize button in div when condensing a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My "home" button goes up into the div as I condense the page. What is the best way to stabilize the button so that it will stay in center of the div as the page is condensed? I've tried many different things and so far nothing has worked so I'm hoping someone on this site could help me answer this problem. I've tried many different things without success.

JS/CSS/HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  //mouseenter overlay
  $('ul#gallery li').on('mouseenter', function () {

    // Get data attribute values
    var title = $(this).children().data('title');
    var desc = $(this).children().data('desc');

    //validation
    if (desc == null) {
      desc = 'Click To Enlarge';
    }

    if (title == null) {
      title = '';
    }

    //Create overlay div
    $(this).append('<div class="overlay"></div>');

    //Get the overlay div
    var overlay = $(this).children('.overlay');

    // Add html to overlay
    overlay.html('<h3>' + title + '</h3><p>' + desc + '</p>');

    // Fade in overlay
    overlay.fadeIn(400);
  });

  $('ul#gallery li').on('mouseleave', function () {

    //Create overlay div
    $(this).append('<div class="overlay"></div>');

    //Get the overlay div
    var overlay = $(this).children('.overlay');

    //Fade out overlay
    overlay.fadeOut(200);
  });

});
```

```css
body{
  background-color: white;
  font-family:Orbitron;
  color:white;
  width:100%
}

.fa-stack-overflow{
color: #f48024
}

.fa-github{
color:rgb(102,43,129);
}

.fa-linkedin{
color:rgb(0,127,178);
}

.fa-facebook-official{
color:rgb(59, 89, 153);
}

.nav-pills{
font-size: 1.7em;
background-color: none;
margin-bottom: 10%;
color:white;
}


.block{
  background-color: #337ab7;
  opacity: .7;
  padding:10px;
  width:50%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  border-radius:5px;
}


h1{
  padding:0;
margin-top: 0px;
font-size: 5.0em;
}

.btn-default{
font-size:1.7em;
color:#337ab7;
}


.pageOne{
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/311039/pexels-photo-311039.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb);
  background-repeat: none;
  background-size: cover;

  height: 1000px;

}

/*
parallax effect start
*/
.pageOne, .pageThree{
position: relative;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
}



/*
parallax effect end
*/

.pageTwo{
background: white;
color:#337ab7;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
height: 400px;
padding-top: 5%;
border-bottom:#00bfff 3px solid;
border-top:#00bfff 3px solid;
background-attachment: fixed;
}


.boxed{
  font-size: 1.7em;
text-align: center;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-bottom: 100px;
}




.me{
height: 850px;
  display:block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;

}

.pageThree{
background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/311039/pexels-photo-311039.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb);
background-repeat: none;
background-size: cover;
height: 800px;
padding-top:6%;
background-attachment: fixed;
}

.button{
  background-size: contain;
}

.container{
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
  overflow:auto;
}

section{
  padding:20px 0;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
  margin-top: 2.5%;
}

#gallery{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#gallery li{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 23%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 12px 7px 0;
  position: relative;
}

#gallery img{
  width:100%;
  border-radius:5%
}

.overlay{
  display:none;
  background:#337ab7 url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/311039/pexels-photo-311039.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb) no-repeat top center;
  color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  z-index:100;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  padding:20px;
  border-radius:5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: .7;
}

.overlay h3{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.pageThreeFooter{
  background: black;
  color:#337ab7;
  background-repeat: none;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 150px;
  padding-top: 2.5%;
  background-attachment: fixed;

}



.pageFour{
  background: white;
  color:#337ab7;
  background-repeat: none;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 2.5%;

}

.black{
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
<title>Daniel's Portfolio | Welcome</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<div class="pageOne text-center">
  <ul class = "nav nav-pills">
<li>
  <a href="#">Daniel Collins</a>
</li>
<li class="pull-right">
  <a href="#p4">Contact Me</a>
</li>
<li class="pull-right">
  <a href="#p3">Portfolio</a>
</li>
<li class="pull-right">
  <a href="#p2">About Me</a>
</li>
</ul>

<div class="block text-center" id="p1">
<h1>Daniel's Portfolio Website</h1>
<h2>Various Web Projects</h2>
</div>
<div class = "btnList text-center">
  <a class = "btn btn-default" href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/7024823/daniel"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow"  aria-hidden="true"></i>Stack Overflow</a>
  <a class = "btn btn-default" href="https://github.com/casteyes"><i class="fa fa-github"  aria-hidden="true"></i>GitHub</a>
  <a class = "btn btn-default" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/daniel-collins-927b1ab0/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"  aria-hidden="true"></i>Linkedin</a>
  <a class = "btn btn-default" href="https://www.facebook.com/daniel.p.collins1"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official"  aria-hidden="true"></i>Facebook</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class= "pageTwo text-center" id="p2">


      <h2>Daniel Collins</h2>
<div class="boxed">
      <p class="black">
        I’m a web developer and designer living in Jacksonville, Florida, United States. I spend my days with my hands in many
         different areas of web development from back end programming (MySQL, PHP, C#, Java) to front end engineering
         (HTML, CSS, and jQuery/Javascript), digital accessibility, user experience and visual design.
</p>
</div>

    </div>
<div class= "pageThree" id="p3">
<header>
<div class="block text-center">
  <h1 class = "logo">Portfolio</h1>
</div>
</header>
<section>
<div class="container">
  <h1 id="heading">Projects</h1>
  <ul id="gallery">
    <li><a href="" data-title="Project 1" data-desc="This is the first project"></a> <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/311039/pexels-photo-311039.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"></li>
    <li><a href="" data-title="Project 2" data-desc="This is the second project"></a> <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/311039/pexels-photo-311039.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"></li>
    <li><a href="" data-title="Project 3" data-desc="This is the third project"></a> <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/311039/pexels-photo-311039.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"></li>
    <li><a href="" data-title="Project 4" data-desc="This is the fourth project"></a> <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/311039/pexels-photo-311039.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"></li>
    <li><a href="" data-title="Project 5" data-desc="This is the fifth project"></a> <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/311039/pexels-photo-311039.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"></li>
    <li><a href="" data-title="Project 6" data-desc="This is the sixth project"></a> <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/311039/pexels-photo-311039.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"></li>
    <li><a href="" data-title="Project 7" data-desc="This is the seventh project"></a> <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/311039/pexels-photo-311039.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"></li>
    <li><a href="" data-title="Project 8" data-desc="This is the eighth project"></a> <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/311039/pexels-photo-311039.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<div class="pageThreeFooter text-center">
  <div class="row">
  <a href="#p1" class="btn btn-primary btn-x2 text-center">Home</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class= "pageFour text-center" id="p4">
  <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                      <h2 class="section-heading">Let's Get In Touch!</h2>
                      <hr class="primary">
                      <p class="black">Ready to start your next project with us? That's great! Give us a call or send us an email and we will get back to you as soon as possible!</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                      <i class="fa fa-phone fa-3x sr-contact"></i>
                      <p class="black">555-5555</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
                      <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-3x sr-contact"></i>
                      <p class="black"><a class="black" href="mailto:casteyestothesun@gmail.com">myemail.com</a></p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you wonder what is the "best" way to go, it often means StackOverflow isn't the right place to ask about it. Primarily opinion-based answers are not what people look for here... and the "best" way could be argued about in may ways.

Comment: And when you _see_ a question that is titled/mainly asks, _"what is the best way to do X"_, then that 9 out of 10 times basically translates to, _"I have done eff all to research this on my own, and expect you to now list all the possible ways to do X for me, and also rank them by their 'bestness', even though I have not even specified any criteria ..."_

Comment: _"Just was wondering the best way to go about this would be for someone who is pretty new to this."_ - that would probably be to go an read up on and research this topic, that is clearly one of the most discussed ones in the web dev community. Also known as making an effort.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to this site. I was just kind of in tough spot with the design... I didn't expect to get this much hate just for asking about something i didn't know much about...

Comment: @Daniel it's not about hating against you, it's about criteria a question in SO should be fulfill: [On-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the important responsive meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

But you are using Bootstrap, which is a responsive framework. So, the answer to your question is to study and understand Bootstrap, along with more general studying of what it means for a site to be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot more to making a website responsive than just changing one or two things. You really need to plan on how each element or container of those elements is going to be responsive in their own right. Also, how your wrap or container of all content will behave as well as how your images, text/font, etc... will also be responsive.

This is too broad a question to be answered simply.

Since you are already using bootstrap, I would research how to utilize this to it's full potential and you can easily make your website responsive.

Answer (score 0):

As you guessed, media queries are a good way to do this.

You'll need to add this tag in your header for these to work:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

There are two ways you can go about setting your breakpoints - by min width or max width.

Since you've already written most of the styles, min-width probably makes more sense. If you have multiple breakpoints you can combine min-width and max-width into a single query to avoid conflicts with other media queries.

As for the home button, I recommend looking up how to vertically center an element. This guide is pretty handy: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/